# Split by attributes with 2 fields

Tags: python, r, vb.net, vb

I am using SplitLayerByAttributes toolbox. It’s a very useful tool for me to process certain activities. As you know, I can split the feature class as per 1 field. What if I want to split the features by 2 fields.
In the below mentioned example:
Here I would like to split the feature based on 2 fields. i.e “parcel_type” and “priority_takes”
Main field is “parcel_type”
Secondary field is “priority_takes” = Corridor

Right now I have run the toolbox twice with 2 different field and you can see the results over here. If at all possible, Splitting a feature with 2 fields then the corridors will be the subdivision in the “Parcel_types” features. Please let me know if you have any solution or any other toolbox available in arcscripts website.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below script just change the parameters- paths names etc.

```
import arcpy,os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1

###Change Below


input = r'C:\Users\\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\AdminBndL'
First_Field ='F_Type'
First_Field_Value = 'Divisional Boundary'
Second_Field = 'RefNamL'
Output = r'C:\Users\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb'
Prefix = '_test'


###Change Above


input = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=input, selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", where_clause="{0} = '{1}'".format(First_Field,First_Field_Value))
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input,"sel")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(input,"CLEAR_SELECTION")
def unique_values(table, field):
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, [field]) as cursor:
        return sorted({row[0] for row in cursor})
flds = unique_values("sel",Second_Field)

for i in flds:
    sql = "{0} = '{1}'".format(Second_Field,i)
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("sel","NEW_SELECTION",sql)
    name = (i+Prefix).replace("  ","").replace(" ","")
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("sel",os.path.join(Output,name))
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("sel","CLEAR_SELECTION")
```